# Cartoon movie I saw around 2000-2010 where people had powers and could walk on clouds. They were looking for a cube

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I can't remember that far back but do remember that anyone could walk on clouds if they were big enough but one fell through, they all had powers of some sort and were trying to find something it was like a cube it was between 2000-2010 thats all i remember.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  There isn't much to this question; it's likely to be closed because we don't have enough information to answer it.  You should take the [tour] and read the [FAQ] to see how the site works, and then try to [edit] in any additional details you can remember about the film/anime.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Ok I'll try to think about it and see what i can remember

Answer (score 1):

### Cloudy with a Chance of Meatballs (2009)

Flint Lockwood, an inventor who is considered a nuisance, puts his latest invention to work when his town faces an economic crisis. His invention makes him popular until it spirals out of control.

[image: Food Machine]

Comment: Clever, but I really doubt that this is the right answer.

Comment: Does that qualify as a cartoon?

Comment: Its not a live-action, so yes.